# Django-Oscar override templatetags

Tags: django, overriding, templatetags, django-oscar

I tried to override category_tags by creating a local version of catalogue application with a local templatetags folder which has a category_tags.py file (also init.py).
It seems the default category_tags file is used.
If I change the name of my local tag file and of course I load the new name of the tag in the template it works but I would like to override or extend the default category_tags not to create another one.

Any ideas?

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I got it working by putting the templates in my project_folder > templates > oscar_app_name > template_name.html

So to override the "checkout" app and template, my structure looks like this:

```
/project
--/apps
----/checkout
------[change checkout models]
----__init__.py
----app.py

--/project
----/templates
------/checkout
--------payment_details.html

----__init__.py
----settings.py
----urls.py

--manage.py
```

And then you have to edit settings.py Installed Apps

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    ...
    'compressor',
    'paypal',
] + get_core_apps(['apps.checkout'])
```

Comment: Dude he asked for template tags. You're answering what there is already given in docs.

Comment: @Jay Sorry. This question was asked and answered before version 1.0 came out. I'm not sure what was in the docs then, but this answer is definitely no longer relevant.

Answer (score 0):

I would assume that template tags get loaded in the order specified in `INSTALLED_APPS`. Does the app containing your `category_tags.py` come before (or instead of, e.g. when using Oscar's `get_core_apps` override to extend an Oscar core app) `oscar.core.apps.catalogue`?

PS. I'm an Oscar author and have to admit we don't check StackOverflow very often. The mailing list is your best bet at the moment.